# Python-Telegram-Bot ConversationHandler unable to receive Message

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am using the Python-Telegram-Bot Package. My telegram bot is unable to receive a message at state `FIRST`. After sending my bot `/start` , I am prompted the text message as shown in `start_command`. However, after sending a url to the bot, the bot is unable to receive the message as seen in the 'single tick' at the bottom right of my message.

```
# Stages
FIRST, SECOND = range(2)

def start_command(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text("""
To use: 
1. Send the google sheets URL and sheet name to this telegram bot in the following format:
your_google_sheets_url (your_sheet_name)
""")
    global user_id
    user_id = update.message.from_user['id']

    return FIRST


def select(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    if update.message.text:
        user_input = update.message.text
        update.message.reply_text('I have received your Google Sheets!')
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_menu(button_list, n_cols=1))
    update.message.reply_text('Please choose the headers:', reply_markup=reply_markup)

    return SECOND
```

```
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_command))
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start_command)],
        states={
            FIRST: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, select)],
            SECOND: [CallbackQueryHandler(display)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
    )
    dp.add_handler(conv_handler)
```

Comment: You need to clarify a few things first like which **telegram Bot** package you are utilizing and add your Error with a little more context on the problem.

Comment: @SumitJaiswal thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the `CommandHandler` for `start` should not be added. This is because when the user inputs `/start`, the `CommandHandler` is called to handle the command instead of the `ConversationHandler`.